# Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', inspite of DateTime kind is set to "Local"

Tags: c#, postgresql

linqToDb + C# + Postgres DB.

I create DateTime and set kind:

```
DateTime dt = someDate.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Local)
```

and use entity for some table

```
[Table("my_table", Schema = "myScheme")]
public class TableEntity 
... [Column("dt", DbType = "timestamp without time zone", DataType = DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DT { get; set; }...
```

and in code I set value of the entity

```
tableEntity.DT = dt;
//In debugger I see, that here Kind for tableEntity.DT is DateTimeKind.Local
```

But In next row I start LinqToDb command:

```
dataConn.InsertWithInt32IdentityAsync(loanContractEntity);
```

and somehow DateTimeKind changed to UTC and then throw an exception:
Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

But I need use 'timestamp without time zone'.

How to write DateTime by LinqToDB in DB field 'timestamp without time zone'?

PS: If I use nullAble DateTime? in Entity definition - all work fine.

```
public DateTime? DT { get; set; }
```

Thanks!

my extension Metod to set kind:

```
public static DateTime SpecifyKind(this DateTime value, DateTimeKind kind) => DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, kind);
```

Comment: `someDate.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Local)` is not a usual syntax. Do you have your own extension method?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen  Yes, you right, I've added that exstension method in the question.